# Why is my first review ban (as far as I know) immediately 15 days?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I just started reviewing a few days ago and got banned for making an incorrect choice on a question:

> Your review on triage/25504941 wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing"
>   should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to
>   edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is
>   unsalvagable/unanswerable and/or can only be improved by the author,
>   please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see
>   meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148.
>
> Come back on Mar 19 at 6:15 to continue reviewing.

I should have just voted to close. I even commented on the question asking for more clarification from the OP.

**My question is - why is my ban immediately 15 days?** It seems a little harsh for a first mistake... Or is there something I don't know? Everywhere I looked it says first ban would be 2 days.

Comment: Because it was a manual ban handed by a moderator. Mods are cracking down in misuse of "requires editing", for educational purposes.

Comment: @yivi, no that is not a duplicate because **that is not my question**. My question was about duration, and **not** why I got banned even though everyone agreed. You can post your comment about the "manual ban" as an answer, but this is not a duplicate of the other question by any means.

Comment: If you read the answers, you'll see they apply to your question.

Comment: @yivi, I have read the only answer that there is. It doesn't cover 15 day duration explanation. I understand **why** I got banned. Sure, a mod can apply a custom ban, but surely there should be guidelines. If I'm missing a very clear sentence in that answer, please let me know. But I do not see anything about arbitrary ban durations?

Comment: @Catsunami: **All** manual ban durations are at the discretion of the moderator applying the ban. 'Requires editing' is a big problem, and shorter bans were going unnoticed (users not returning to the site for longer than the ban applied for). Moreover, you made this mistake on *three separate posts*, you also made this mistake on https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25504794 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25502501, the duration went from 4, to 8, to 16 with each failure the moderator in question found.

Comment: @Catsunami: as the purpose of the ban was to get your attention and to educate and you've indicated you understand why the ban was applied, I've lifted the review ban now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks, I only got the warning about the latest one when I checked review queue. That's what I was curious about - if there was something behind the scenes that I didn't know. Since it wasn't for 1 mistake, 15 days makes sense.